# Multiple Checkboxes in a row

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I want to create a page with multiple options (checkboxes). Here's what I got so far:

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Title here</legend>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="Option 1">
      <label for="AG-Wahl">1</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="Option 2">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">2</label>
      </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="Option 3">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">3</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="Option 4">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">4</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="Option 5">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">5</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="6" name="Option 6">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">6</label>
     </div>
     <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="7" name="Option 7">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">7</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="8" name="Option 8">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">8</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="9" name="Option 9">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">9</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="10" name="Option 10">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">10</label>
     </div>
    
</fieldset>
```

Now I want to put 3 options in one row next to each other, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many ways to achieve this. In my opinion the easiest way to do this would to use the combination of `display: inline-block;` and `width:30%`.

Why? Because you need only to add this lines of code without changing your entire html.

```css
fieldset div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;  
}
```

```css
fieldset div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;  
  margin:5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Title here</legend>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="Option 1">
      <label for="AG-Wahl">1</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="Option 2">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">2</label>
      </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="Option 3">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">3</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="Option 4">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">4</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="Option 5">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">5</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="6" name="Option 6">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">6</label>
     </div>
     <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="7" name="Option 7">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">7</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="8" name="Option 8">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">8</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="9" name="Option 9">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">9</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="10" name="Option 10">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">10</label>
     </div>
    
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Is there any way to limit it to 3 boxes checked at the same time?

Comment: @yScruffii You welcome! :-) If you found my answer helpful it would nice if you accept this answer. To your question: Yes it is possible with javascript.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do I accept an answer?

Comment: @yScruffii On the left side from my answer you will find a upvote, downvote button. And a votingscore. Below this you will see a check mark. If you click on it will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use CSS grid.

This snippet puts your options into a container '.choices' and then tells the grid that it wants 3 columns. The container is given a width - depends on what you want as to what that is. This snippet just gives it a width in terms of character width.

UPDATE: a new requirement is to center the whole set of options. This could be done various ways. The snippet has been altered to use flex on a container. To increase the space between options you can just set a gap.

```css
legend {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.choices {
  display: grid;
  gap: 4em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <legend>Title here</legend>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="choices">

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="Option 1">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">1</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="Option 2">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">2</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="Option 3">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">3</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="Option 4">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">4</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="Option 5">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">5</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="6" name="Option 6">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">6</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="7" name="Option 7">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">7</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="8" name="Option 8">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">8</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="9" name="Option 9">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">9</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="10" name="Option 10">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">10</label>
      </div>

      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Obviously you will want to play around with the various settings to get the sort of spacing you want.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. How can I center that whole option-thing on my page and how can I make more space between the options in one row?

Comment: I have updated the answer. To learn more about positioning with grid and flex see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 0):

you can separate the div

```html
<div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="Option 1">
      <label for="AG-Wahl">1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="Option 2">
      <label for="AG-Wahl">2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="Option 3">
      <label for="AG-Wahl">3</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="Option 4">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">4</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="Option 5">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">5</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="6" name="Option 6">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">6</label>
     </div>
     <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="7" name="Option 7">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">7</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="8" name="Option 8">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">8</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="9" name="Option 9">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">9</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="10" name="Option 10">
        <label for="AG-Wahl">10</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: HTML tags should not be used for styling! The divs separate the inputs into kind of groups which makes semantically no sense (here).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way if you are using bootstrap

```
  <form>
    <div>
      <label for="option1" class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="option1">1
      </label>

      <label for="option2" class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="option2">2
      </label>

      <label for="option3" class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="option3">3
      </label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="option4" class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="option4">4
      </label>

      <label for="option5" class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="option5">5
      </label>

      <label for="option6" class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="6" name="option6">6
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="option7" class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="7" name="option7">7
      </label>

      <label for="option8" class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="8" name="option8">8
      </label>

      <label for="option9" class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="9" name="option9">9
      </label class="checkbox-inline"l>
    </div>
    
    <label for="option10" class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="10" name="option10"> 10
    </label>
  </form>
```

Comment: OP did not mention the use of bootstrap though

Comment: You can separate  with <div> </div>  as many checkbox you want to show in a row.